# I have a probleam with arsenal package: after I download the package I cannot use and load it because I got this error:

Tags: r, package

After having downloaded arsenal package I cannot use/load it because I get this error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arsenal’ in rbind(info,
> getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):  number of columns of matrices
> must match (see arg 2) In addition: Warning message: package ‘arsenal’
> was built under R version 4.1.0

Can you please help me?

Comment: What version of R do you have?

Comment: I have the version 3.5.3. I cannot install and load many packages. Is there an new version of R studio ?

Comment: R and RStudio are two different things. You need to update R, which is now at version 4.0.2 (there must have been an error in your message above, as there is no way that package was built in v4.1.0, I assume it meant 4.0.1).